# How to add more details to JPA validation exceptions

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

I have a Spring Boot (JPA / Hibernate) application with `javax.validation` validation annotations and when I perform transactions on entities I receive these cryptic exceptions:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.voverc.eventmanager.eventservice.service.event.EventServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ea57e22c.archiveEvents(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor435.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.voverc.eventmanager.eventservice.domain.PhoneCall] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=originatorNumber, rootBeanClass=class com.voverc.eventmanager.eventservice.domain.PhoneCall, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=direction, rootBeanClass=class com.voverc.eventmanager.eventservice.domain.PhoneCall, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=originatorName, rootBeanClass=class com.voverc.eventmanager.eventservice.domain.PhoneCall, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=destinationName, rootBeanClass=class com.voverc.eventmanager.eventservice.domain.PhoneCall, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way to customize this kind of exceptions (via Spring or Hibernate), for example adding the identifier of the object? How can I know on which kind of object the validation has failed (imagine an update of hundreds of elements)?

Comment: This is nothing to do with the JPA API. It is bean validation API (where those annotations come from)

Comment: But `BeanValidationEventListener` is responsible to call the validation and throw the exception. Is there no way to customize it with additional data?

Comment: Why you don't write your custom event listener if the provided doesn't fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can set validation message in bean validation annotations:

```
@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull(message = "{name.NotNull.message}")
@Size(min = 3, max = 9999, message = "{name.Size.message}")
private String name;
```

to set the message, you create `ValidationMessages.properties` in your resources, where you store error statements, e.g:

```
name.NotNull.message=Name should not be null
```

Comment: I don't want more detail on the wrong fields. Rather I would like to know which object is wrong (e.g. printing its identifier)

Comment: @AlessandroDionisi you can get validated property in message, e.g `name.Size.message=Name '${validatedValue}' is not valid, it should be between {min} and {max} characters`
If that's not enough, you should write custom ConstraintValidator, which will give you access to whole bean object